# Elements dont position back to normal after resizing browser window

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float, window-resize

im building this site, and i need it to be responsive.
http://design.imago.ee/REC/html/index3.html

Im new to responsive css and media queries.
In this site i have 2 inputs and 2 selects wrapped by #filters form.
When i resize the window to small size like 900px wide, the inputs and selects position like
i want them to, but when i maximize browser window back to normal, then those inputs and selects wont position themselves back like they were in the beginning unless i refresh.
Any idea what am i doing wrong? 
I use media query like this: `@media only screen and (max-width: 960px)`

a picture describing the situation http://design.imago.ee/REC/filters.jpg

Comment: It looks alright in Safari. Which browsers are you testing in?

Comment: in my safari(win7) and chrome it doesnt look ok, but in firefox it looks okay.

Comment: I see that you are using a combination of floats and `relative`/`absolute` positioning for your elements. I would suggest that you go with either `relative`/`absolute` positioning, or use `inline-block`.

This does not explain the issues you are having with media queries, but it might still fix the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: giving #filters a min-width seems to solve the problem.